# ASPNET 6 TagHelper context not maintained when using an editor template

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

Given some parent / child TagHelper(s).

Parent

```
[HtmlTargetElement("div", Attributes = "parent-context")]
public class AspFormViewTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    [HtmlAttributeName("parent-context")] 
    public string? Prefix { get; set; }

    public override void Init(TagHelperContext context)
    {
        context.Items["parent-context"] = Prefix;
    }
}
```

Child

```
[HtmlTargetElement("input", Attributes = "asp-for, child-context")]
public class AspForVueTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")] public ModelExpression For { get; set; }

    [HtmlAttributeName("child-context")] public String ChildContext { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (!context.Items.ContainsKey("parent-context"))
            return;
        var prefix = (string) context.Items["parent-context"];
        // The above is null when using an editor template?
    }
}
```

When rendering HTML, this works perfectly.

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="person" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab" parent-context="parent">
<div class="row mb-1px">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input asp-for="@Model.Person.FirstName" child-context="child" />
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

However, if I render an Editor Template, then the context is lost.

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="person" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab" parent-context="parent">
    @Html.EditorFor(_ => _.Person.FirstName, "boot-text-child")
</div>
```

With `boot-text-child.cshtml` containing this....

```
<div class="row mb-1px">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input asp-for="@Model" child-context="from-editor-template" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The parent context is gone.
**Why does the heirarchy of rendering break down when an editor template is used. Is there any way to force the rendering so that the context is maintained for an Editor Template.**

The child is correctly called both times, but when the editor template is used, the `context.Items` is empty.

Comment: Why you didn' t try to use asp webforms helpers as well? perfect is the enemy of good. Don't touch if it is working

Comment: I don't follow?

Comment: Why do you need outdated editor-for helper when the newest one asp-for is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might relates the scope of TagHelperContext, I checked your code on my side and set some break point in the custom tag and relate view page, it seems that when using the following code:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="person" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab" parent-context="parent">
<div class="row mb-1px">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input asp-for="@Model.Person.FirstName" child-context="child" />
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The break point order is: Main page => AspFormViewTagHelperc.cs => AspForVueTagHelper.cs

But if using Editor Template and `@Html.EditorFor`, the order is: Main page => AspFormViewTagHelperc.cs => Editor Template page => AspForVueTagHelper.cs.

If I put the `parent` div into the Editor Template page, the `context.Items` contains the value. The Editor Template page code like this:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="person" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab" parent-context="parent">
<div class="row mb-1px">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input asp-for="@Model" child-context="child" />
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

In the main page, only using the `Html.EditorFor`, like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(_ => _.Person.FirstName, "boot-text-child")
```

[image]

So, you can use this method to render the elements or directly using the tag helper instead of using `@Html.EditorFor`.

Comment: Thanks, what you say makes total sense. That's what I was seeing.
When you mention "or directly using the tag helper" what do you mean by that?

Its there another way to get the child to render?

It should actually work, this is a bug in my opinion, but there are also probably better ways to do this.

Comment: Hi @Jim, "When you mention "or directly using the tag helper" what do you mean by that?" I mean using the tag helper to display the data, instead of using `@Html.EditorFor` and the Editor Template. "Its there another way to get the child to render?" I also checked other methods, such as partial view, it still have the same issue. I suggest you could also submit a feedback on the [Asp.net core Github forum](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues), then the asp.net core development team will verify whether it is a bug or is there have a better way to do it.